# Detect objects from live YouTube video and generate links

Tags: python, object-recognition, imageai

I am working on a small project where I'd like to create a browser extension to work with Youtube (or other streaming sites) to detect trendy items in the video and generate purchase links which will be shown in a column (the idea is not completely well fledged out yet). I am using ImageAI library for detecting the images. Live camera feed can be captured in OpenCV VideoCapture() function and then passed to detectObjectsFromVideo() function of ImageAI.

Can someone please tell me how can we modify this to work with youtube videos?
I don't think Pafy/Youtube-dl will satisfy the need as it downloads the video, which is not the ask here. From the user perspective: If I turn on this extension then on watching a video, objects should be detected and corresponding links should be generated for a nice customer experience.

Will be awesome to hear your ideas as well.

Comment: and what have you researched so far in terms of how to make it work while the user is watching the video? I doubt you will be able to create a browser extension as that requires js (unless you create your own browser), so it will be a desktop application and basically you probably just want to take screenshots of user's screen and process those

Comment: @Matiiss what I've researched so far is written on my question. The idea was to have an object recog system to work with existing video streaming sites. In that case, taking screenshots/frames and then processing will not be feasible for real time results.

Comment: well, then take more screenshots a.k.a. screen-record user's screen, that will create a video stream that you can try to detect objects in, and also it is impossible to have real time results since no matter what it will take time to process the video and in that time the video will have moved further so capturing screenshots is definitely good enough, it is not like you have to capture a screenshot only every five minutes, you can screenshot every second or half a second if the program or user's computer are fast enough

Comment: @Matiiss thank you. I was thinking if it would be possible to have something similar to Amazon Prime's XRay feature. The only part I need help with is to capture live video from youtube (and not download).